# Publish sbt assembly without ivy xml file

Tags: sbt

I'm making a GUI app in ScalaFX for private use and want `sbt publish` to make a **fat jar** with sbt-assembly and put it **alone** into a local folder to share with my friends.

I don't want extra files that come with it automatically (pom, md5, sha1, source, javadoc, lightweight jar and ivy config) or nested directories. With this config, I was able to disable everything but the **ivy-XX.xml** file.

```
name := "my-app"
version := "2.1"

// ...deps and scalac config...

artifact in (Compile, assembly) := {
  val art = (artifact in (Compile, assembly)).value
  art.copy(`classifier` = Some("assembly"))
}

addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, assembly), assembly)
checksums in publish := Seq()
publishArtifact in packageBin := false
publishArtifact in packageDoc := false
publishArtifact in packageSrc := false
publishMavenStyle := false

publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", file("D:/Dropbox/my-app"))(Patterns("[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]")) )
```

How do I disable ivy xml too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured that if I use maven-style publishing:

```
publishMavenStyle := true // which is default anyway
```

then POM file can be discarded by simply:

```
publishArtifact in makePom := false
```